Migration Issues from MarketingCloudSDK 7.6.0 to 8.1.2 version
We are using MarketingCloudSDK 7.6.0 as an embeded xcframework in our iOS project, but we're migrating to MarketingCloudSDK 8.1.2 with SPM following the migration guide.
When we execute the app with this new version of the SDK over an app with the MarketingCloudSDK 7.6.0 version, we are getting these errors in the console related to CoreData:
CoreData: error: Failed to stat path '/Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application/78019FF5-9000-47DB-8504-7E02D01EB0D4/Library/MarketingCloudSDK_7C69FD1E-B600-4678-B3D4-D3F721C9FF6B.datastore', errno 2 / No such file or directory.
CoreData: error: Executing as effective user 502
CoreData: error: Failed to statfs file; errno 2 / No such file or directory.
CoreData: error: Logging status information for directory path: /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application/78019FF5-9000-47DB-8504-7E02D01EB0D4/Library
CoreData: error: Executing as effective user 502
CoreData: error: Information for /
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       640 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      2
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        0
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       0
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is not writeable with errno 30
CoreData: error: Information for /Users
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       224 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      14490
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        0
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       80
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is not writeable with errno 13
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       1664 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      482740
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   750
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       3104 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      482747
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   700
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       256 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      1569991
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       192 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      1570023
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       2208 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      1570053
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       128 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      75444224
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       384 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      75444227
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   775
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       224 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      77708045
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       192 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      77708054
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       3872 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      77709268
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application/78019FF5-9000-47DB-8504-7E02D01EB0D4
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       224 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      77720027
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application/78019FF5-9000-47DB-8504-7E02D01EB0D4/Library
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       704 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      77720029
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error: returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain (512)
CoreData: error: userInfo:
CoreData: error:    reason : File unexpectedly appeared during sanity check
CoreData: error: storeType: SQLite
CoreData: error: configuration: (null)
CoreData: error: URL: file:///Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application/78019FF5-9000-47DB-8504-7E02D01EB0D4/Library/MarketingCloudSDK_7C69FD1E-B600-4678-B3D4-D3F721C9FF6B.datastore
CoreData: error: Failed to stat path '/Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application/78019FF5-9000-47DB-8504-7E02D01EB0D4/Library/MarketingCloudSDK_7C69FD1E-B600-4678-B3D4-D3F721C9FF6B.datastore', errno 2 / No such file or directory.
CoreData: error: Executing as effective user 502
CoreData: error: Failed to statfs file; errno 2 / No such file or directory.
CoreData: error: Logging status information for directory path: /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application/78019FF5-9000-47DB-8504-7E02D01EB0D4/Library
CoreData: error: Executing as effective user 502
CoreData: error: Information for /
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       640 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      2
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        0
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       0
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is not writeable with errno 30
CoreData: error: Information for /Users
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       224 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      14490
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        0
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       80
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is not writeable with errno 13
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       1664 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      482740
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   750
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       3104 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      482747
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   700
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       256 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      1569991
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       192 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      1570023
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       2208 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      1570053
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       128 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      75444224
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       384 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      75444227
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   775
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       224 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      77708045
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       192 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      77708054
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       3872 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      77709268
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application/78019FF5-9000-47DB-8504-7E02D01EB0D4
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       224 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      77720027
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: Information for /Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application/78019FF5-9000-47DB-8504-7E02D01EB0D4/Library
CoreData: error:   File Device ID:  0
CoreData: error:   Device ID:       16777233
CoreData: error:   File Size:       704 bytes
CoreData: error:   File inode:      77720029
CoreData: error:   File user ID:        502
CoreData: error:   File group ID:       20
CoreData: error:   File Permissions:    
CoreData: error: d
CoreData: error:   755
CoreData: error:   component is not a symbolic link
CoreData: error:   component is readable
CoreData: error:   component is writeable
CoreData: error: addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error: returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain (512)
CoreData: error: userInfo:
CoreData: error:    reason : File unexpectedly appeared during sanity check
CoreData: error: storeType: SQLite
CoreData: error: configuration: (null)
CoreData: error: URL: file:///Users/{my-user}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5AD83851-E4CA-4AD1-B75C-C561CC04AD75/data/Containers/Data/Application/78019FF5-9000-47DB-8504-7E02D01EB0D4/Library/MarketingCloudSDK_7C69FD1E-B600-4678-B3D4-D3F721C9FF6B.datastore

It looks like some Core Data model migration related to MarketingCloudSDK that the app cannot resolve properly.
Our project doesn't use Core Data at all.
Obviously, if I remove the old version of the app and I do a fresh install, these issues disappear, but we're afraid about our current users not getting the app working properly.
Any help to solve this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Looking at the error seems to be Simulator permission issue, request to check this.
Also, recommend to follow the steps for migration of SDK to 8.x provided here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/mobilepush/guide/migrate-ios-sdk.html to ensure smooth transition to 8.x version of SDK.
Please reach out to the salesforce support team if the issue still persist even after following all the steps.
Thanks,
Prakashini
